# Checking for orthogonality of $\cos(\pi x)$ on the set of functions ${\sin(n\pi x)}$ in the $[0,1]$ interval

Tags: integration, fourier-series, orthogonality

I'm trying to verify the orthogonality of the function $\cos(\pi x)$ to the set of functions $\{\sin(n\pi x)\}, n=1,2,3...$,on the $[0,1]$ interval, for which I have taken the integral obtaining the following result:

$$\int_0^1 \cos(\pi x)\sin(n\pi x) dx= \begin{cases}   
  0 & \text{if $n \gt 1$, and if n odd} \\ \frac{n(1+(-1)^n)}{\pi(n^2-1)}  & \text{if $n \gt 1$, and if n even} \end{cases}$$

But the source I'm reading states (with no proving) that the result is:
$$\int_0^1 \cos(\pi x)\sin(n\pi x) dx=   
0 \text{ if $n \neq 1$} $$

Is this the case? I've verified multiple times my calculations by hand and software and still my result differs from the one in the book.

---

More info:
The original part of the problem was the following claim about the fourier coefficients of the function $\cos(\pi x)$ respect the set of eigenfunctions $\varphi_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x)+n\pi\cos(n\pi x)$ with $n=1,2,3...$ in the interval $[0,1]$
$$a_n=\int_0^1 \cos(\pi x)[\sin(n\pi x)+n\pi\cos(n\pi x)]= \begin{cases}   
  0 & \text{if $n \neq 1$} \\ \frac{\pi}{2}  & \text{if $n = 1$} \end{cases}$$

Comment: It seems like you should get zero when $n=1,$ since $\cos(\pi-y)=-\cos y, \sin(\pi-y)=\sin(y).$

Comment: When $n=1$ your integral is equal to $$\frac12\int_{0}^1\sin(2\pi x)\,dx=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin y\,dy=0
$$ It seems like something is wrong with your question. Are you sure this is the integral?

Comment: I think you're right. $\cos(n\pi x)$ and $\sin(m\pi x)$ form an orthogonal set on the interval $[-1,1]$, not on the interval $[0,1]$. (Although, I'm pretty sure that for $n=1$, it's still zero.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yep, pretty sure, same for the interval.

Comment: How are you getting $\pi/2$ for $n=1?$ Since $\cos(\pi x)\sin(\pi x)|<1,$ the integral cannot be greater than $1.$

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the $\pi/2$ comes from another result previous on the problem. I'll edit to ignore that case.

Comment: I’m still suspect. Why would the source say $n\neq 1,$ when it is zero when $n=1,$ too? What is the source?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it is "Problems and exercises in integral equations by M. Krasnov" page 122 if you are wondering.

Comment: It is true, however, that $\cos(\pi x)$ is orthogonal to $\cos(\pi n x)$ on $[0,1]$ when $n\neq 1.$ I suspect that was what the book meant, but hard to say.

Comment: With your final addendum, you can see that the set of orthogonal functions that you are expanding in is $\sin(n\pi x)+n\pi\cos(n\pi x)$, and so really this has nothing to do with the orthogonality of $\cos(\pi x)$ and $\sin(n\pi x)$. The functions $\sin(n\pi x)+n\pi\cos(n\pi x)$ form an orthogonal set (and complete) set on $[0,1]$ (with some set of boundary conditions), and so the function $\cos(\pi x)$ can be expanded in that set. (Or something like that.)

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos (\pi x) \sin (n \pi x) = \frac{1}{2} (\sin (\pi x + n \pi x) - \sin (\pi x - n \pi x)) = \frac{1}{2}(\sin (\pi (n + 1) x) + \sin (\pi (n - 1)x)$$

We consider only the case where $n \neq 1$.

Taking the integral from $0$ to $1$ gives $\frac{1}{2\pi} (\frac{1}{n + 1} (1 - \cos((n + 1) \pi)) + \frac{1}{n - 1} (1 - \cos((n - 1) \pi)))$.

When $n$ is odd, we have $\cos((n + 1) \pi) = \cos((n - 1) \pi) = 1$ and thus the integral is $0$.

When $n$ is even, we have $\cos((n + 1) \pi) = \cos((n - 1) \pi) = -1$, and thus the integral is $\frac{1}{\pi} (\frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{n - 1}) = \frac{2n}{\pi(n^2 - 1)}$.

Finally, in the case that $n = 1$, we see that we're integrating only $\frac{1}{2} \sin(2 \pi x)$ from $0$ to $1$. This integral works out to be 0.

So the integral is always equal to $0$ when $n$ is odd, and $\frac{2n}{\pi (n^2 - 1)}$ when $n$ is even.

Thus, both you and the book are wrong in the case $n = 1$. You are correct on all other cases.

Comment: $\frac{n(1+(-1)^n)}{\pi (n^2-1)}= \frac{2n}{\pi (n^2-1)}$ when $n$ is even

Comment: @ppmbb Right, but they both got the case of $n = 1$ wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the functions $\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{L} x\right)$ and $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L} x\right)$ form an orthogonal set of functions on the interval $[-L,L]$. In the case of the OP, we have $L=1$ for the functions, but we are only integrating over half of the interval, i.e., $[0,1]$.  These functions are *not* generally orthogonal on the interval $[0,L]$, as the OP has demonstrated.  (Although $\cos(\pi x)$ and $\sin(\pi x)$ are actually orthogonal on $[0,1]$. Otherwise, the OP is correct.)

Comment: OP hasn’t “demonstrated,” merely asserted. The error when $n=1$ shows these assertions are suspect, and the fact that the book has the same error when $n=1$ implies we might not be getting the correct information.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, okay, but the expression for $n>1$ ($n$ even) is correct, so I assumed they had calculated that, and that's where the problem with the book lies anyway, unless of course the OP just read the limits wrong.

Comment: I’m feeling like the OP likely is reading it wrong. The title in terms of orthogonality and the result given are the result of orthogonal if it’s about $\cos(\pi x)$ and $\cos(n\pi x).$